# SQL Count Where on a specific date... but the result is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, count, where-clause

Hi it is NOT my first time the i use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.SchDetail WHERE dbSchDate = '08-06-2020'
```

Query is working but he counts everytime 0.

But if i do a `between "08-06-2020" and "07-06-2020"`.

I got the right result.

For mysql both query working fine.

But not on MSSQL.

I dont know what I do wrong.

Thanks for help

Comment: What's the datatype of `dbSchDate`? And what value for that attribute do you get when you use `between '08-06-2020' and '07-06-2020'`?

Comment: Most likely your dates contain hours / minutes / seconds. You probably need to use `BETWEEN`.

Comment: what's data type of dbSchDate ? if its datetime , you are not passing time , and its assumed it is '08-06-2020 00:00:00' and you  don't have any match at this date and time

Comment: this is the format in the database  1999-11-09 15:59:10.000

Comment: What is the datatype of `dbSchDate` ? I gues it's a `DateTime` or `DateTime2` and in that case there is a time portion you also need to provide. Or you can cast the `DateTime`to a `Date`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `0` because the `WHERE` clause filters out all rows.  There are multiple reasons; for instance:

- The table could be empty.
- `dbSchDate` could be a `datetime` with a time component.
- The constant may not be interpreted correctly as a date/time.
- No values in the table might match.

I would suggest a proper date format, in YYYYMMDD format:

```
WHERE dbSchDate = '20200806'
```

You can also use:

```
WHERE dbSchDate >= '20200806'
      dbSchDate < '20200807'
```

This version works even if there is a time component, as does:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dbSchDate) = '20200806'
```

Comment: OHHH Yes thank you very much this does the trick.......select COUNT(*) from dbo.SchDetail
WHERE CONVERT(date, dbSchDate)='08-06-2020'

Comment: @RobertDietrich . . . Use the standard formats for dates -- either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Comment: @RobertDietrich Note also Gordon's correct use of the half open interval `>= AND <` not `>= AND <=` (the latter is the same as `BETWEEN`)